# How to change background of the checkbox in unchecked state

Tags: react-native, checkbox, native-base

In my react-native app (using native-base as the component library). I have been trying to change the background color of the checkbox in the unchecked state but the default **white** background is not changing.

[image]

react-native: "0.68.5"
native-base: "3.0.3"

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time and trying out multiple ways I was able to find the solution.

Add this piece of code to your theme file, change the color you want and you are good to go.

---

```
  Checkbox: {
      baseStyle: {
        _checkbox: {
          bg: "#faf3de",
        },
      },
    },
```

---